# Filename as columns - hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

I have log files with that contain the date and hour in the file name. Is there a way to extract date & hour from the filename to add extra columns in hive, an example of the file is weblogs-20150101-010000.gz.

The method that I know is to sequentially append the date and hour to each line using a map only job, but I am trying to see if there an easier method via hadoop streaming.

Answer (score 0):

If query performance is important and you'll be filtering by the date/hour, you could [partition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions) the data by placing the files in folders that contain the date attributes, e.g. `/path/to/your/data/year=2015/month=05/day=25/hour=14/`, then add those partitions to the Hive table.

Another approach would be to use Hive's `INPUT__FILE__NAME` virtual column and filter using that, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM WEBLOGS WHERE INPUT__FILE__NAME LIKE '%20150101-010000.gz'
```

Comment: hey Alex, thank you for you comment. The number of files that I have is close to 10,000. Is there an easy way to arrange them into folders?

Comment: You could write a script to copy them into the appropriate folders. Perhaps someone else has a better solution.